# Hibernation Dell Inspiron 5565 and Ubuntu 18.04 Doesn't Wake Up

Tags: dell, hibernate

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Del Inspiron 5565. It sleeps fine, for short periods, but after it hibernates it won't resume. The backlit keyboard comes on, but there is no key response from say CapsLock and pressing the power button does nothing. I've made sure the power button is set to power off and not suspend in power settings. 
I tried the AMD 18.20 preview video card drivers and there was no difference, so I reverted to the built-in drivers. The behavior is the same with both sets of drivers.
I checked my BIOS settings too and there were no options to disable hibernation. 
So, is anyone else having this issue? What did you do to resolve it? The system passed hardware tests.

Comment: I've done some more digging into this. Looks like Ubuntu has disabled hibernation for some time now. So it must be the hardware doing it. So I edited the file  sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
I set the lid switch line to:
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
I'll see what happens. This idea came from here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/
I am not 100% sure how this relates to 18.04. Does 18.04 disable hibernation by default? I think it must since only power off, suspend and nothing are my options for power button behavior in system settings.

Comment: Editing logind.conf did not solve the problem.  However, I update to 4.15.0-23-generic today. I will close the lid and see what happens in the morning.

Comment: I have the same laptop, and I have never had hibernate work on this machine with any version of Ubuntu. Suspend used to work better... in 18.04 I can suspend, but resume fails about every third time. It's not nearly that consistent though. Do you have that problem too?